# Why dropdownlist values is persisted with isPostBack and not DataTable which contains that list?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have DataTable which feeds a dropdown list. The values of this dropdown persist when I click on the button whereas the datatable which feeds the list is null at next page reload. I need that this dataTable to also persist like its associated control so isn't there anything that asp.net has in its tricks bag to behave like for controls but for private members instead ?

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private DataTable m_DataTable = new DataTable();

    private void f(String x, String y){
        // some function of x,y
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            m_DataTable.Columns.Add("Title");
            m_DataTable.Columns.Add("x");
            m_DataTable.Columns.Add("y");

            m_DataTable.Rows.Add("place1", "1", "2");
            m_DataTable.Rows.Add("place2", "3", "4");


            int nTotalRecords = m_DataTable.Rows.Count;
            for (int i = 0; i < nTotalRecords; i++)
            {
                DropDownList1.Items.Add(m_DataTable.Rows[i]["Title"].ToString());
            }


            DataRow[] dataRowArray = m_DataTable.Select("[Title]='place1'");
            String x = dataRowArray[0]["x"].ToString();
            String y = dataRowArray[0]["y"].ToString();

            f(x, y);

        }


    }


    protected void ButtonGo_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // this code will crash because m_DataTable is emptied when page reloads
        DataRow[] dataRowArray = m_DataTable.Select("[Title]='place2'");
        String x = dataRowArray[0]["x"].ToString();
        String y = dataRowArray[0]["y"].ToString();
        f(x, y);
    }
}
```

Update: I heard that asp.net paradigm was to be as close as possible as desktop. Why does  it create a new instance for the page instead of keeping it ? Why does it keep the same state for controls and not for private members that is incoherent isn't it?

Comment: Can someone clarify this? I can't tell what the question is.

Comment: The private members are not reset. There is a new instance of the Page object created for each request, so all members are brand new and has nothing to do with any members of instances from previous requests.

Comment: OK but it's not coherent model to be able to consider the page as a single instance for controls and new instance for private members don't you think ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put it in view state:

```
Page.ViewState["DataTable"] = m_DataTable;
```

and retrieve it after postback:

```
m_DataTable = Page.ViewState["DataTable"];
```

The drawback is of course that the serialised data is sent to the client and back again, which increases the weight of the postback.

Another alternative is to store it in the user session:

```
Session("DataTable") = m_DataTable;
```

and retrieve it after postback:

```
m_DataTable = Session("DataTable");
Session.Remove("DataTable");
```

The drawback of that is of course that you increase the memory load on the server.

Consider the drawbacks of each method, and weight that against how much it costs to get the data again. Sometimes time is the cheapest resource.

Comment: That should be one of my next question when I would try to manage user session ... I'm just not there yet but thank you for being in advance will avoid me future mistake :)

Comment: What's difference (advantage/disadvantage or context use) between your's and egrunin solution ?

Comment: @user310291: You don't have to manage sessions, each visitor has a session (and a session cookie) unless you specifically create session-less pages. What egrunin suggests is what I am talking about in the last paragraph; loading the data on each request instead of persisting it.

Comment: I heard that asp.net paradigm was to be as close as possible as desktop. Why does it create a new instance for the page instead of keeping it ? Why does it keep the same state for controls and not for private members that is incoherent isn't it?

Comment: @user310291: Yes, webforms try to mimic the desktop applications environment as closely as possible, but because the environments are fundamentally different, there are some things that can't reasonably be done. Keeping one instance of each page in memory for each visitor is simply not possible.

Comment: @Guffa ok that seems to make sense will think more about it :)

Answer (score 2):

If the data in the table does not change, don't put it inside `if (!IsPostBack) {}`

Comment: What is better your solution or the one below with viewstate ?

Comment: I tried that works but don't you agree that asp.net is not very logical in this case ?

Comment: This doesn't persist the `DataTable` at all, but loads it on every request. That might be a good alternative, but it should be mentioned that it's not what the OP asked for.